# How to plot row by row across multiple columns in R?

Tags: r

[image]

Each row represents a location therefore I would like to create a different graph for each row. Any idea how to do that? I have tried melt() but that does not work because it group everything as one. And I want to make 2 distinct barcharts or linegraph here with months on the x-axis

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page. Questions should provide the data reproducibly using `dput`, not as images, since no one else can easily use the data from images without retyping. Also question is not at all clear what you want. First it says you want a graph for each row and then it says you want 2 graphs.  Which is it?  Please provide code of your best attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `data.frame()` only has numerical values (so that we don't lose any information by conversion to a matrix) we can make use of the automatch of names in `apply()`.

**Code**

```
# Align plots horizontally
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))

# One plot per row
apply(df, 1, function(x){
  barplot(x, las = 2)
})
```

[image: Plot Output]

**Data**

```
df <- as.data.frame(rbind(rnorm(12), rnorm(12)))

names.m <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")

names(df) <- names.m
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by turn the direction of your data frame. For example:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2), b = c(2,4))
> df
  a b
1 1 2
2 2 4
df <- data.frame(t(df))
df$group <- rownames(df)
> df
  X1 X2 group
a  1  2     a
b  2  4     b

## Then you need the library ggplot2
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = X1, y = X2, color = group)) +
  geom_point()
```

I hope this would help.